# Change default calendar starting weekday in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, date-time

In the "Date and Time Properties" dialog of Windows XP (reachable by double-clicking on the time/date on the taskbar) the week in the calendar starts on Monday. I would like to change it so that it starts on Sunday. How can this be done?

Comment: I thought there was something under the Regional and Language Options control panel applet, but I've just double checked and there's nothing there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's region specific. I have Windows XP set up with Romanian regional settings; that automatically changes the first day of the week to Monday, but you can't change only that setting by yourself.

However, looking over [this thread](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/55988-35-first-week-issue) over on tomshardware.com, there is a registry setting that can change this. I'm not sure what will happen, but you can take a look there and see (though I strongly recommend not mucking about with the registry unless it's really needed and you know what you're doing):

> This is locale specific and may have
>   been changed based on where he said 
>   he is located. The value is stored in
>   the registry at 
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control
>   Panel\International. With that key
>   selected  you will see an
>   iFirstDayOfWeek entry in the right
>   pane. Have him  change the value there
>   from 0 to 6.

Comment: It turned out to be regional indeed. Once I've changed it from the U.K to U.S region, it shifted to Sunday as the first day

Answer (score 5):

It's basically tied to the region you have configured in XP (Control Panel > Regional and Language Options). For example, if I set my region to English (United States) then the calendar starts on a Sunday:

[image: USA calendar]

If I change the region to English (United Kingdom) then the calendar starts on a Monday:

[image: UK calendar]

I don't think there is any other way to configure it.

Comment: Sorry for what seems like a late answer on this, it got merged from another question.

Answer (score 1):

There definitely is: for instance my setting is English (US) but I have overridden the starting day of week by change in registry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\iFirstDayOfWeek=0
```

and now my week starts with Monday as I want.